# separate rmiregistry and server application

Tags: java, rmi

I'm developing a basic application that starts the rmiregistry at the server:

```
try {
            // create the registry and bind the name and object.
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(thisPort);
            registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

I want to run the registry on another machine. Is it possible to separate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to run the registry on another
>   machine. Is it possible to separate
>   this?

Its possible.  If the registry is running on a different machine, you can locate it using [LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html#getRegistry(java.lang.String,%20int))